# Directory listing batch file

Tags: batch-file, dir

I have this batch file code

```
dir /a:d /s /b | sort
```

I can't seem to get it to output the information to a text file. I tried this

```
dir /a:d/s/b/o:n | sort > Folder Listing.txt
```

but nothing happens. I can get the command prompt to pause on screen by doing

```
dir /a:d /s /b | sort
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your listing to go into a file called `Folder Listing.txt`, you need to enclose it in double quotes:

```
dir /a:d /s /b /o:n | sort > "Folder Listing.txt"
```

This is valid for most if not all operations on the Windows shell which involve file names containing spaces.